# React-leaflet: Map refreshes zoom value to default despite onViewportChanged handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, local-storage, react-leaflet

I have a Map component which is storing some state in local-storage for the map.

That being said, I'm setting the initial state of the `zoom` attribute, then using the `onViewportChanged` attribute on the map, to have a handler listen for the changes one would make to the `zoom` attribute, and then setting the value from the handler to the zoom attribute.

UserContext component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

var initialState = {
  currentMapProps: { zoom: 18 }
};

var UserStateContext = React.createContext();
var UserContextDispatch = React.createContext();

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  function userReducer(state, { type, payload }) {

    switch (type) {

      case 'setMapZoom': {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...{ currentMapProps: payload.currentMapProps.zoom }
        };
      }

      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${type}`);
      }
    }
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getLocalStorage('user', initialState));

  var [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, user);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('user', state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <UserStateContext.Provider value={{ state: state }}>
      <UserContextDispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch: dispatch }}>
        {children}
      </UserContextDispatch.Provider>
    </UserStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function userState() {
  const context = useContext(UserStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('userState must be used within a UserProvider');
  }
  return context;
}

function userDispatch() {
  const context = useContext(UserContextDispatch);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('userDispatch must be used within a UserProvider');
  }
  return context;
}


export default UserContextDispatch;

export { UserProvider, userState, userDispatch };
```

Then in my Map component:

```
import { userState, userDispatch } from '../Context/UserContext.jsx';

export default function MyMap({}) {
  var [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
  var [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);

  var mapRef = useRef();
  var mapRefForRoutingMachine = useRef();
```

**Update:** This is where the references from context begin. The **state** object is getting destructured here, so I can then destructure the UserContext properties.
Same for **dispatch** except it’s a function

```
  var { state } = userState();
  var { dispatch } = userDispatch();
  var {
    currentMap,
    currentMapProps,
    } = state;

  function handleOnViewportChanged(viewport) {
    var { current = {} } = mapRef;
    var { leafletElement: map } = current;
    if (map != undefined && currentMapProps != undefined) {
      var { zoom } = viewport;

      dispatch({
        type: 'setMapZoom',
        payload: {
          currentMapProps: {
            zoom
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <Map
      onViewportChanged={handleOnViewportChanged}
      preferCanvas={true}
      zoom={() => {
        if (currentMapProps != undefined) {
          var { zoom } = currentMapProps;
          return zoom;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }}
      ref={mapRef}
      onClick={e => handleWaypointsOnMap(e)}
    >
 
    </Map>
  );
}
```

So is there something I'm not aware of that's causing the map to refresh as ignore my handler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are `userState` and `userDispatch`? You show that you export them from your first file, but not where you define them?

Comment: They’re on top of the Map file, then being invoked so I can destructure the values.

Comment: We can see them imported in your map, exported by your UserContext, but nowhere they are defined.

Comment: I updated the question for you to show the destructuring...

Comment: Sorry this still does not show what are those functions, whereas it seems to me they probably play a role in your issue. Destructuring and importing is not the point here, it is what these functions do, hence how you define them.

Comment: Maybe you have renamed them from `var [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, user);`?

Comment: @ghybs So sorry mate, I misunderstood you. I updated the question!